# Using enhanced for loop to search LinkedList

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list

So im trying to replace a for loop with a enhanced for loop and i cant get it to work, the problem is that it does search and when it finds the name im looking for it returns inex -1. With the normal for loop it returns the correct index. n is the string passed to the method, array is the linkedlist

```
boolean found= false;
    for(O o: array) {
        if(o.getString().equals(n)) {
            System.out.println("\n"+n+ " is found at position " +array.indexOf(name)+"\n");
            found = true;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<array.size();i++) {
        if((array.get(i).getString()).equals(n)) {
            System.out.println("\n"+n+ " is found at position " +i+"\n");
            found = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you need the index, don't use the enhanced for loop.

Comment: @Eran ah so you are saying its not possible or just its a waste of time in this case trying to figure it out

Comment: You can always add an int variable that would keep track of the current index, but there's no point in doing so, since the regular for loop already gives you the index.

Comment: Note that using `indexOf` is going to do the search again. Also, where does `name` come for? You were looking for `n`!

Comment: @RealSkeptic sorry name is n i was just typing short hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use array.indexOf(o)

Answer (score 1):

Index is a bit circumstantial, as `indexOf` needs the entire O object; an `Optional<O>` is easier. `array.indexOf(n)` should have been `array.indexOf(o)`.

```
Optional<O> foundO = array.stream().findAny(o-> n.equals(o.getString()));
int index = foundO.mapToInt(o -> array.indexOf(o)).orElse(-1);

System.out.println("\n"+n+ " is found at position " +index+"\n");
```

As you see the newer Stream API removes the need for some for/forEach loop.